# mkdir not working in centos 7?

Tags: bash, shell

I have this little bash script that I'm writing to create files in  particular directory by reading lines in a file. But the issue is mkdir is not creating dir, not sure why and it is working I try it outside the script. Below is my script...

```
#!/bin/bash -x

source credentials.sh
OPTARG=""
while getopts :i:x:n name
do
    case $name in
        x)  inputfile="$OPTARG" ;;
        i)  outputPath="$OPTARGS" ;;
        n)  dirName="$OPTARG" ;;
    esac
done

if [ ! "$dirName" ]
then
    mkdir $dirName || echo "error while creating dir"
fi
while read -r line;
do
    touch "$line"
    mv  "$line" "$dirName"
done < $inputfile
```

ERROR:

```
 [root@Buy]# ./prepare_messages.sh -x file.txt -n testdir
 mkdir: missing operand
```

I searched and tried few but not working, can someone please shed some light...

Thx,

Arun

Answer (score 1):

`[ ! "$dirName" ]` doesn't test whether the directory exists, it just tests whether the string `$dirName` is empty or not. You need:

```
if [ ! -d "$dirName" ]
```

You should also quote the variable when calling `mkdir`:

```
mkdir "$dirName" || echo "error while creating dir"
```

Your `getopts` call is wrong. The `:` character goes *after* the option that takes the argument. Since you don't have `:` after `n`, `$OPTARG` wasn't being set for that option, so `$dirName` is always empty. It should be `getopts i:x:n: name`.

There's also no `$OPTARGS` variable, that should be `$OPTARG`.

The full correction:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

source credentials.sh
OPTARG=""
while getopts i:x:n: name
do
    case $name in
        x)  inputfile="$OPTARG" ;;
        i)  outputPath="$OPTARG" ;;
        n)  dirName="$OPTARG" ;;
    esac
done

if [ ! -d "$dirName" ]
then
    mkdir "$dirName" || echo "error while creating dir"
fi
while read -r line;
do
    touch "$line"
    mv  "$line" "$dirName"
done < "$inputfile"
```

Comment: I would add a check to see if `$dirName` is empty. Otherwise, whenever `$dirName` is empty, `[ ! -d "$dirName" ]` will evaluate to true and he'll end up getting the same missing operand error from `mkdir`. Edit: Although, it looks like the script relies on `$dirName` not being empty. Still good to check though.

Comment: Hi @Barmar, tested as you said but throws me mkdir: cannot create directory ‘’: No such file or directory if [ ! -d "$dirName" ]
then
    mkdir  "$dirName" || echo "error while creating dir"
fi

Comment: @MikeHolt, thanks for suggesting, I did checked and it's empty. Not sure why ?

Comment: Updated the answer with more problems in your code. You should have been able to tell these things from the trace output of `-x`.

Comment: `++ [[ 2 -gt 1 ]]
++ return 0
+ OPTARG=
+ getopts :i:x:n name
+ case $name in
+ inputfile=file.txt
+ getopts :i:x:n name
+ case $name in
+ dirName=
+ getopts :i:x:n name
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ echo '$dirName is empty'
$dirName is empty
+ '[' '!' -d '' ']'
+ mkdir ''
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘’: No such file or directory
+ echo 'error while creating dir'
error while creating dir`

Comment: Don't you see `dirName=` which is assigning an empty string to `dirName` when it's processing the `n` option? That's because of the incorrect `getopts` argument.

Comment: Above is result after adding -x @Barmar

Comment: It's because you wrote `getopts :i:x:n` instead of `getopts i:x:n:`. Don't you see that in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Got it working, below is corrected line of code. Missing ":" at end of getopts args...

```
while getopts :i:x:n: name
```